# C++ Multi-Client TCP Server with QList

Tags: c++, qt, tcp, qlist

Necessary informations:

```
  QList<QTcpSocket*> list;
  QTcpServer* server;
  QTcpSocket* socket;
```

In Qt I have built a TCP-Server(**QTcpServer**)! I have a **QList** with all my connected clients and I want to read the incomming data for each client personally. So if the **QTcpServer** gets a new connection, I handel it like this:

```
void Server::newConnection()
{
   qDebug() << "New Connection";
   list.append(server->nextPendingConnection());
   connect(list.last(),SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readyRead()));
}
```

How can I get the correct client (out of my **QList**), which send the **SIGNAL** `readyRead()`, in my **SLOT** `readyRead()`?

```
void Server::readyRead(){
       //??
}
```

Any help is welcomed!

Comment: Answers do not belong in the question. It is OK to answer your own question - in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The solution:**

```
void Server::readyRead(){

    QByteArray buffer;
    QTcpSocket* readSocket = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender());
    buffer = readSocket->readAll();

    QString mytext = QString::fromStdString(buffer);
    qDebug() << mytext;
}
```

Comment: text = buffer ?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried QObject::sender()? It should return the instance of the QObject which actually sent the signal. Hope that will help.

Comment: **Yeah, thank you!** `sender()` is the right way to do this! If anybody like to do something with my code, it is above!

Comment: How to you use sender() ? I tried ` QTcpSocket* socket  = QObject::sender();`

Answer (score 1):

This could be solved by the `QSignalMapper`. Here is the (not completelly tested) code:

---------------------- main.cpp ------------------

```
#include "rootwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    RootWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

---------------------- rootwindow.h ------------------------

```
#ifndef ROOTWINDOW_H
#define ROOTWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QLocalServer>
#include <QLocalSocket>
#include <QSignalMapper>
#include <QList>

class RootWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:

    QLocalServer *server;
    QLocalSocket *socket;

    QList<QLocalSocket*> *list;

    QSignalMapper *mapper;

public:

    RootWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~RootWindow();

private slots:

    void slotNewConnection();
    void slotReadyRead(int index);
};

#endif // ROOTWINDOW_H
```

------------------------ rootwindow.cpp -------------------------

```
#include "rootwindow.h"

RootWindow::RootWindow(QWidget *parent): QMainWindow(parent)
{
    server = new QLocalServer;
    list = new QList<QLocalSocket*>;

    mapper = new QSignalMapper(this);

    connect(server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(slotNewConnection()));
    connect(mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(slotReadyRead(int)));

    server->listen("TestServer");
}

RootWindow::~RootWindow()
{
    delete list;
}

void RootWindow::slotNewConnection()
{
    qWarning() << "newConnection";
    list->append(server->nextPendingConnection());

    //here you map each client to its number in the list
    mapper->setMapping(list->last(), list->length()-1);

    //here we say, that when ever a client from the QList sends readyRead() the mapper should be used
    //with the property (list->length()-1) defined in the line above
    connect(list->last(), SIGNAL(readyRead()), mapper, SLOT(map()));
}

void RootWindow::slotReadyRead(int index)
{
    qWarning() << "Client " << index << " has written: " << list->at(index)->readAll();
}
```

It's basically your code, I've only added the `QSignalMapper` and some comments at the relevant lines.